# Abort HTTP Response After Headers Sent

Tags: http

I'm working on a web application.

Requirements keep cropping up which would need the server to cancel a download after it has started (headers and some data sent to client).

The right solution is to push back against these requirements. I know this.

Assuming the requirements stand, what is the least wrong way to implement this? Is there a valid (if obscure) way to do it within the HTTP specs, or a way that is invalid, but that most user agents will detect as a server error?

Comment: You are free to close the TCP connection at any time. Of course, the client will detect this as an error: "Connection reset by peer". What is the client behaviour you expect?

Comment: The expected client behaviour is for the client to do as little as possible with it, because it knows the data is no good. If possible, it should not cache the response. If possible, it should not attempt to render (or otherwise make available) half-complete data to the user. If possible, it should report an error to the user. I doubt that all of these things is possible, but what's the best we can do?

Comment: Well, as I wrote, depending on programming language and HTTP library you are using, just close the connection while download is in progress. This will raise a TCP error on client, and most HTTP clients (browsers) will discard the download. Still, as data has been sent to the client, it *could* decide to keep all data already received.

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping someone has experience of which ways are less likely to lead to that sort of behaviour. I know that if there's no content-length, and it's not using chunked encoding, then closing the connection is just the standard way of signalling end-of-file, so I need either content-length or chunked encoding. But are there tricks that can improve the odds of the client recognising something's gone wrong? Does it help to use gzip compression (I know gzip checksums are at the end)? What if I send a chunk with a garbled chunk header?

Comment: I'm not sure if you ain't making things more complicated than they are... did you **test** any of these approaches?

Comment: Not yet. That's my next step. But I was hoping that either there was a better approach that I hadn't been able to think of, or that someone else had faced this exact issue before.